# Updating DB with data from a third party API

Tags: sql-server, database, asp.net-core, synchronization

My company uses a third party app for employee time tracking / timesheets. I am currently working on an internal project that is supposed to use some of the data from this third party app. I am getting the data using the API they are providing and syncing it to my project database. I did this by implementing IHostedService, since I had a code sample to follow. The data is automatically synchronized each Monday morning.
I am curious what other/better options are there to do this task. My project is using the Asp.Net Core 2.0 framework.

Comment: What problems do you face with the implementation you have at the moment?

Comment: @junkangli colleagues doubting it would be the best way. without much argumentation as to why that would be :))

Comment: Have you looked at running schedular? You can try hangfire https://dotnetthoughts.net/integrate-hangfire-with-aspnet-core/

Comment: Is there an advantage to using asp.net core and running it through a web server?  Not sure if it is a framework you are trying to fit into. Could do a command line app and schedule it to run and eliminate and web server requirement.